# Not receiving WM_QUERYENDSESSION when minimized to system tray

Tags: winapi, mfc, system-tray

I'm trying to catch WM_QUERYENDSESSION to save some data in the app, but it seems that I'm not receiving this message on User logoff/system restart when the app is minimized to the system tray. How can I catch it?

Thanks.

Relevant code (nothing magic in there, hopefully :)):

```
ON_WM_QUERYENDSESSION()

BOOL CMainFrame::OnQueryEndSession()
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Are we hitting this?");

 return FALSE;
}
```

For the tray icon I'm using a third-party lib (CodeJock), which I probably can't post here, but generally, it creates a hidden window to process messages, but the main window is simply ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) when needed. Maybe I need to intercept that message in that hidden window and pass it up, I'll need to try that.

Comment: I think we would need to see some of your code. Specifically the tray minimize and WM_QUERYENDSESSION code.

Comment: Yeah, definitely need to see some code here. I've seen problems with MFC apps where WM_QES messages were aborted by IME helper windows returning FALSE (turning off advanced text services solved that), but I've never seen a case where logoff worked but my app didn't see the message.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I've added some more explanations to the question. I'm happy to provide more code of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically eaten by a third-party class that I'll need to fix up.